# Function to pull product URL from Order details page in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I am using woocommerce bookings plugin and I am looking for a solution for customers who have already booked a time slot to be able to add more time to their booking.  In theory, it would be great if they could just edit their booking and pay the difference but from what I can tell that would require an extensive amount of custom code which I am not capable of doing.  So as an alternative solution, perhaps I can create a unique button on the customer's order detail page at `/my-account/booking-details/OrderID/` where they can go to a specific product based on the product of that order.

I have created a custom hook on the /order-details.php file called woocommerce_extra_time_button and added the below code to my theme's function.php file but I am not able to pull the product URL as I thought I would.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_extra_time_button', 'booking_extratime_button', 10, 3 );
function booking_extratime_button( $item_id, $item ){
    $url = get_permalink( $item['product_id'] ) ;

    return '<a href="'. $url .'">'. $item_id .'</a>'; 
}
```

Comment: What is the value of $url?

Comment: $url is supposed to be the URL of the product on the order detail page.  Thats what I am trying to get but seem to have issues doing so.  I am a bit new to woocommerce and hooks so perhaps I am missing something? If I am please advise. Thanks.

Comment: I can see that is what it should be. What value is it actually?

Comment: Sorry I should have put that in originally. it is giving me a fatal error message:  Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function booking_extratime_button(), 1 passed in /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286 and exactly 2 expected in /wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php:51 l

Comment: Can you share wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php line 286

Comment: lines 283 - 289 are:  `if ( $the_['accepted_args'] == 0 ) {
     $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array() );
    } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
     $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
    } else {
     $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args'] ) );
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the product detail from the order of current user and use inside your custom hook. for example :

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items()
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_name = $item->get_name();
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    $product_variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info. Can you elaborate your code snippet to show how I could gather the product URL for the order?

Comment: You can pass the product id which you get from the $item inside foreach above code :     
                                                                                   
$url = get_permalink( $product_id ) ;